# Easy way to extract common measures such as accuracy, precision, recall from 3x3 confusion matrix with numpy or pansas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRwxA.png)

Hi there, do anyone knows how to speed up this process. Just a easy way to extract common measures such as accuracy, precision, recall, f-score from 3x3 confusion matrix only with numpy or pandas? Any suggestions? I am attaching you a image with the my outcome.

```
cm =confusion_matrix.to_numpy()
acuracy_0 = np.round_(cm[0][0]/cm[3][3], 2)
acuracy_1 = np.round_(cm[1][1]/cm[3][3], 2)
acuracy_2 = np.round_(cm[2][2]/cm[3][3], 2)
acuracy = (acuracy_0, acuracy_1, acuracy_2)
col1 = np.array(acuracy)

precision_0 = np.round_(cm[0][0]/cm[3][0], 2)
precision_1 = np.round_(cm[1][1]/cm[3][1], 2)
precision_2 = np.round_(cm[2][2]/cm[3][2], 2)
precision = (precision_0, precision_1, precision_2)
col2 = np.array(precision)

recall_0 = np.round_(cm[0][0]/cm[0][3], 2)
recall_1 = np.round_(cm[1][1]/cm[1][3], 2)
recall_2 = np.round_(cm[2][2]/cm[2][3], 2)
recall = (recall_0, recall_1, recall_2)
col3 = np.array(recall)

f_score_0 = np.round_((2*precision_0*recall_0)/(precision_0 + recall_0), 2)
f_score_1 = np.round_((2*precision_1*recall_1)/(precision_1 + recall_1), 2)
f_score_2 = np.round_((2*precision_2*recall_2)/(precision_2 + recall_2), 2)
f_score = (f_score_0, f_score_1, f_score_2)
col4 = np.array(f_score)

d = {'Acuracy': col1, 'Precision':col2, 'Recall':col3, 'F1_score':col4}
measurs = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
measurs.index.name = 'Class_Label'
measurs
```

Comment: Please add your confusion matrix as **text** not images.

Comment: I don't know if scikit-learn is allowed for you. If it is, an option could be https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, code like

```py
accuracy_0 = cm[0][0]/cm[3][3]
accuracy_1 = cm[1][1]/cm[3][3]
accuracy_2 = cm[2][2]/cm[3][3]
accuracy = (accuracy_0, accuracy_1, accuracy_2)
```

can be replaced with the more concise

```py
accuracy = cm.diagonal()[:-1]/cm[-1,-1]
```

so you might rewrite your code as

```py
cm = confusion_matrix.to_numpy()
diag = cm.diagonal()[:-1]

accuracy  = diag / cm[ -1, -1]
precision = diag / cm[  3,:-1]
recall    = diag / cm[:-1,  3]
f_score   = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)

out = pd.DataFrame({'Accuracy': accuracy, 
                    'Precision': precision, 
                    'Recall': recall,
                    'F-score': f_score}).round(2)
```

Comment: Thanks man, that is really neat code! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @YordanИванов Check that you're using `f_score   = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)`? I realised I had (mistakenly) used `np.dot(precision, recall)` instead of `np.multiply(precision, recall)` which can simply be written `precision * recall`

Comment: Good stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with pandas dataframe, you can do:

```
# df is your confusion_matrix
# these are your classes
classes = df.columns[:-1]

# the true positives
true_positives = np.diagonal(df.loc[classes, classes])

accuracy = true_positives / df.loc['All','All']
precisions = true_positives / df.loc['All', classes]
recalls = true_positives / df.loc[classes, 'All']
fscores = 2 * precisions * recalls / (precisions + recalls)

out = pd.DataFrame({'accuracy': accuracy, 
                    'precisions': precisions, 
                    'recall': recalls,
                    'fscore': fscores
                   }, index=classes           # in case your classes are different from 0,1,2,...
                   ).round(2)                 # round all at once
```

Output:

```
   accuracy  precisions  recall  fscore
0      0.17        0.38    0.67    0.48
1      0.14        0.38    0.31    0.34
2      0.08        0.43    0.27    0.33
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response!

Comment: It raises an KeyError: "None of [Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='object', name='Predicted')] are in the [columns]". Do you know why is that?

Comment: You need to replace `df` in my code with your confusion matrix.

Comment: Ok, cheers. That helped!